# Branch of Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using regular (not multibranch) pipeline job which getting Jenkinsfile from repository. And I would like to checkout the same branch in my script. Currently I could use job name as branch name:

`checkout(scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: env.JOB_BASE_NAME]], ...)`

But it is not always convenient and it is still 2 places which should be changed - job name and branch name which is error prone. I only found [open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47226) and suggestions to use multibranch pipeline which is overkill in my case.

Is there a way to access branch name used to checkout Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Why do you consider the multibranch pipeline overkill? It's very convenient IMHO.

Comment: it does not fit current job structure - we currently group jobs from different repos by branch and in multibranch pipeline you would have different grouping or I would have to create multiple multibranch jobs each limited to single branch - which does not look nice. Basically in this particular case I would like to fit in current approach - proper usage of multibranch pipelines is much bigger task which I cannot do now.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right , all you need to do is get the job a parameter and pass that parameter in the checkout step :

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${env.PARAM}"
```

Here PARAM is the name of the parameter you added in the build configuration.

Comment: There are multiple options how to specify branch name in 2 places - this approach is error prone. I'm looking for solution where branch specified only once.